# Importing Spreadsheet to SharePoint 2013

Tags: excel, import

when attempting to import a Spreadsheet from Excel to SP13, I get the error "List cannot be imported because SP Foundation-compatible spreadsheet is not installed or compatible with your browser.

Answer (score 1):

[image: I am giving you three solutions here]

Try this

1. Go to Tools in IE
2. Click on Internet Options
3. Click on Programs at the top
4. Click on “Manage add-ons” near the bottom
5. Click on Publisher, so you can see all of Microsoft Corporation together
6. Scroll to SharePoint names (May be one or several)
7. Make sure they are all enabled by clicking on the name; the Enable button is towards the bottom.
8. Then click OK and OK and restart IE

---

### 2nd solution

Or try this
Solution: Use Internet Explorer 32 bit version!

[image]

How to Open Internet Explorer 32 bit version? Go to start >> Type "Internet Explorer" and pick the "Internet Explorer" link as in this screenshot.

[image]

Error: The specified file is not a valid spreadsheet or contains no data to import.
I'm sure the data is valid and in right format. I know the data is in right format, What's wrong? 
[image]

Solution: Well, SharePoint 2013 expects your SharePoint 2013 site to be in Trusted Sites List! So, Add your SharePoint site to Trusted Sites zone.

Here is How to Add SharePoint Site to Trusted Sites Zone:
Go to Internet Explorer >> Click on "Tools" Menu >> Internet Options >> Security >> Trusted Sites >> click on "Sites" button and Enter the URL of your SharePoint Site >> Click on "Add".

---

### 3rd solution

Also also check the below add-ons are enabled in Internet explorer. Open IE click on Settings Icon -> Manage Add-on and check the below add-ons are enabled.

SharePoint Export Database Launcher
SharePoint Spreadsheet Launcher
SharePoint Stssync Handler

[image]

After this the error The list cannot be imported because a Microsoft SharePoint Foundation-compatible spreadsheet application is not installed or is not compatible with your browser will not appear.

Answer (score 0):

I've just had this issue with Sharepoint 2013. It's because I force IE11 rendering engine for my site collection. To fix it:

1. Press F12 to open the developer bar in Internet Explorer
2. Click at the top right of the developer bar to select `10` instead of `11`
   [image]
3. The page will reload using IE10 rendering engine
4. Do the import